# Properly setting up an array with contact form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms

I have a contact form that is going to use JSON to send errors from the PHP script that will do the validation over to the Javascript for it to display the correct error messages for the user. The goal here is the following:

- Rely upon PHP script to perform the actual validation for security purposes
- Rely upon Javascript only for CSS/HTML design alerts

I have the following **PHP contact form:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
/* Put Here email where you will receive Contact message*/
$yourEmail = "email@email.com"; // <== Your Email
$secret = 'LALALALAALALALALALALA'; // <==Your recaptcha Privte Key
/*---------------------------------------*/

// ---------------------Start the recaptcha ------------------------------------//
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && ($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        session_start();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
    $result = json_decode($response,TRUE);
        if($result['success'] == 1){
            $_SESSION['result'] = $result['success'];
            }

// --------------------End Of the Captcha Check------------------------- //

/////////////Showing all errors in array : DO NOT DELETE THIS
$formerrors = array();
///////////////////This Array will Hold all errors

// Start Captcha
if(!isset($_SESSION['result']) || $_SESSION['result'] == 0){
    $formerrors[] =  'Captcha Error';
}
//end Captcha


// remove this to make name not required
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
$formerrors[] = "Name Cannot be empty";
}
// End name


// Remove this to make email not required
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
  $formerrors[] = "Email Cannot be empty";
}
// End of email

// Remove this to make email not required
if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == FALSE){
  $formerrors[] = "Make Sure Email is valid";
}
// End of email

// Remove this to make Phone not required
if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
  $formerrors[] = "Phone Number Cannot be empty";
}
// End of Phone



// Remove this to make Phone not required
if(!is_numeric($_POST['phone'])){
  $formerrors[] = "Phone Is not valid";
}
// End of Phone



// Remove this to make Message not required
if(empty($_POST['message'])){
   $formerrors[] = "Message Cannot be empty";
}
// End Of Message


// Remove this to make Subject not required
if(empty($_POST['subject'])){
   $formerrors[] = "Select a subject First";
}
// End Of Subject



/* Your New inputs */

    // CODE HERE

/* end of new Inputs*/




// End Showing Errors In Array

//JSON Encode
echo json_encode($formerrors);


if(count($formerrors) == 0){
 // Saving data in variable :
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $title = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    /* Your New inputs */

        // $newinput = $_POST['new-input'] // new-input same as ID and ajax

    /* end of new Inputs*/

    //If No Error in the Array Start Sending the email
    $to = $yourEmail;   // Email to receive contacts
    $from = $email;
    $subject = 'Contact Form Email : ' . $title;
    $message = '<style>
                body{background-color:#fefefe}
                .email-style {padding: 30px;background: #fafafa;font-size: 18px;border: 1px solid #ddd;width: 60%;margin: auto;}
                p {padding: 15px 0px;}
                </style>

                <div class="email-style"><p> '.$title . '</p>

                <p>Contact Full Name : '.$name . ' </p>

                <p>Contact Email : '.$email . ' </p>

                <p>Contact Phone Number : '.$phone . '</p>

                <p>Message : '.$message . ' </p>

                <p>Cheers,</p>
                <p>'.$name.' Via Contact Form</p></div>';

    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
       if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
            echo "sent";
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
          } else {
                   echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
                }
              }
            }
ob_flush();
?>
```

**The Javascript is:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Import JSON
  $("#contactForm").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "formmaster.php",
    data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",

    //If fields have errors
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('form-control-success').addClass('form-control-danger');
    },

    //If fields are successful
    success: function (element) {
        element.text('').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-control').removeClass('form-control-danger').addClass('form-control-success');
    }
});
});
});
```

What I am trying to do is properly setup where the array gathers up all inputs from the fields, checks them for errors and either sends them via email if all is correct or pushes it into an error array and sends that error array to the Javascript.

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Can you narrow this down and remove irrelevant code, please?

Comment: Please read over the [mcve] to help us help you.

Comment: @ChrisG well I am just trying to see how to properly write the PHP script to create an array for successful inputs and an array for errors to send over to the javascript. Last time I did not post the HTML and Javascript I got yelled at.

Comment: @ChrisG ok I cleaned it a bit

Comment: You have a `highlight` propery in your `$.ajax` call, but that doesn't exist in the API and the function is never called. You need to check the PHP reply in `success` (you called `element` for some reason) and compare it to `"sent"`; if it isn't then it's the error array; iterate over it and show the errors next to the the respective fields.

Comment: it is always better to do a client side form validation than calling an php api. Try to use Jquery validate plugin for the form, it is much more easier than php side validation

Comment: @sree "always better"...? Plus, OP already stated they need server validation.

Comment: @ChrisG not looking for it to show errors next to each field, but to highlight the field and display the errors in the main box.

Comment: @kynon Same difference, isn't it? If you don't know how to do this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)